# TimePickerDialog CANCEL and OK button not showing

Tags: android

I have a class that `extends DialogFragment` and inside this class I'm using the `TimePickerDialog`.

The time picker works but the problem is sometimes the `CANCEL` and `OK` buttons don't show, as shown in the images below.

**The buttons work but are invisible.**

Here is the code used for the time picker.

```
public static class TimePickerFragment extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
        implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    // String used to set both Start and end times
    String startEndTime;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        Bundle b = getArguments();

        if (b != null) {
            startEndTime = b.getString("startEndTime");
        }


        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }


    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        // Do something with the time chosen by the user
        switch (startEndTime) {

            case "startTime":

                break;

            case "endTime":

                break;

            default:

                break;

        }

    }
}


public void showTimePickerDialog(String startEndTime) {

    TimePickerFragment timePickerFragment = new TimePickerFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();

    b.putString("startEndTime", startEndTime);

    timePickerFragment.setArguments(b);

    timePickerFragment.show(context.getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems like you're opening the TimePickerDialog inside a dialog. So it doubles, the first one I think is your dialog returning the instance of TimePickerDialog, the second one is the actual TimePickerDialog.

Comment: @TentenPonce yep, and this is how I'm calling it from button clicks:  `code`                                               
                                                         
                                                         
bt_startTime.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            showTimePickerDialog("startTime");
        });

        bt_endTime.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            showTimePickerDialog("endTime");
        });

Comment: Same issue, have you got anyway to fix that?

Comment: @UnokenMouny yep I answered it below :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I fixed the issue, I think for some reasons the font color for the buttons were showing as white sometimes, have no idea why.

To fix the issue, I added a dialog theme to the TimePickerDialog to set the button text color.

Here is the xml code I added to styles.xml

```
<style name="MyTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
     <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
     <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And here is the code I changed.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    Bundle b = getArguments();

    if (b != null) {
        startEndTime = b.getString("startEndTime");
    }


    // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
    return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyTimePickerDialogTheme, this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For me the color of ok and cancel button were white , it was because my colorOnPrimary was set to white .

```
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
```

And Timepicker used it , to fix that you can change that to black or any color you want.

```
<item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
```

Or just add a new colorOnPrimary inside a custom theme and use it for timepicker.

```
<style name="MyTimePickerDialogTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
 <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This was exactly my headache too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem fixed with the following code.

```
<TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timepicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:text="Ok"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />
        </LinearLayout>

    </TimePicker>
```